# R dplyr: select all columns after transforming selected columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble and want to only do some mutation on selected columns. In the case below, all columns which have the word 'date' will be transformed by a function (as.Date()).

After I have performed some transformations on the selected columns, I want to get back all the columns from my tibble df.

Is there a way to do so?

```
df %>% select(contains('date')) %>% mutate_all(as.Date) %>% select(all)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mutate_at` instead of `select` and then `mutate_all`.  This would select only the columns of interest and modify those while keeping the others columns as such

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(contains('date')), as.Date)
```

Comment: Alright, what if I have 3 consecutives transformation on columns containing the word 'date'? For example, after as.Date, I want to apply some lubridate functions as well.

Comment: @AfiqJohari  You can create a function with all the transformations and use that i.i.e. `f1 <- function(x) {x <- as.Date(x); othertransformations}; df %>% mutate_at(vars(contains('date')), f1)`

Comment: Thanks, I think creating another function is not necessary in my context. I will just write consecutive mutate_at(). I think it helps with readability.

Comment: @AfiqJohari  That is fine too for readability.  I would always pass it in a single function